# Should I close a stream (file-like object) passed into my object in the context manager __exit__() function?

Tags: python, file, stream, contextmanager

I have an object which I'd like to be able to use the `with` keyword on. I'm happy with the practicalities implementing context managers but I'm hitting my head up against a best practice kind of issue.

The object is a wrapper around a file. I'm planning for my object to be initialised either with a string (the path of the file) or with a file-like which can be dealt with directly (there's a possibility of files inside files - so I foresee a definite use case for this with BytesIO etc...)

So `__init__`looks something like this:

```
def __init__(self, file_to_process):
    if isinstance(file_to_process, str):
        self._underlying_stream = open(file_to_process, "rb") # it's the path to a file
    elif isinstance(file_to_process, io.IOBase):
        self._underlying_stream = file_to_process # its the file itself
    else:
         raise TypeError()
```

So my question is, is it best practice/acceptable/sensible to close that `_underlying_stream` in my `__exit__()` function? It totally makes sense when it was a path, but if it's a stream passed in, it strikes me as impolite at best and dangerous at worst to close `self._underlying_stream` - **am I correct to be thinking that, and if so, is there a neat way around this?**

(Note: I considered wrapping the stream coming in with a `io.BufferedReader`, but it turns out that closing that will also close the underlying stream...)

Comment: Simplest would be to set `self._close_on_exit = True` when testing for string instance.

Comment: Depends on the context, but for an existing opened stream, I'd probably leave it open, then the caller has the choice as to whether they want to close it afterwards or not. You could use another variable, as Steven suggests, to remember if you need to close the stream or not. Whichever way you decide to go, make sure the behavior is well documented.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right and I considered that but it felt too simplistic, like I was missing something clever. But I suspect that, like usual, Simple is better than Complex...

Comment: If you like, you could add a keyword arg to your method along the lines of `def __init__(self, file_to_process, always_close_stream=False)` which the caller could explicitly set to `True` if they want the stream to be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would *not* close the underlying stream. Passing in an already open file object means the caller has taken responsibility of that object and closing that object on `__exit__` would be extremely annoying, at best.

PIL does something similar, albeit not in a context manager. When passing in a filename, it'll close the fileobject after it completes reading the image data. It sets a boolean flag just for that. Pass in a file object instead and it'll read but not close.

I'd do the same here:

```
class Foo(object):
    _close_on_exit = False

    def __init__(self, file_to_process):
        if isinstance(file_to_process, str):
            self._underlying_stream = open(file_to_process, "rb") # it's the path to a file
            self._close_on_exit = True
        elif isinstance(file_to_process, io.IOBase):
            self._underlying_stream = file_to_process # its the file itself
        else:
             raise TypeError()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self._close_on_exit:
            self._underlying_stream.close()
```

Comment: Simple is better than complex.